# On Function event of button is not loading C# Script?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

I am making a car game in unity 5.0.4f1. I am facing two snags.

1. While installing 3.5 net framework, it gives an error. I searched,
   it took my 2hrs and problem couldn't solve. Then, I reinstalled Unity. For this snag, what is the best solution in a way I won't waste my time anymore?
2. On the other hand, when I added a C# script using VS community 2015, after    dragging the script on the click event, **No function** doesn't show me the script name in the drop down menu. I'm following this tutorial, [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqXJixcYNYU&t=408). At 7:58 he added the script in on function. For me, it is not working.

[image: Game View]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject menu_Canvas;
    GameObject settings_Canvas;

    void Start () {

        menu_Canvas = GameObject.Find ("MainMenu_Canvas");
        settings_Canvas = GameObject.Find ("Settings_Canvas");

        settings_Canvas.SetActive (false);
        menu_Canvas.SetActive (true);
    }

    public void LoadLevel (int a) {

        Application.LoadLevel (a);
    }

    public void Quit () {

        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void loadMenu () {

        menu_Canvas.SetActive (true);
        settings_Canvas.SetActive (false);
    }

    public void loadSettings () {

        menu_Canvas.SetActive (false);
        settings_Canvas.SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

Please help, as I have been trapped in the problem since few days.

Comment: please share your code.do you place script instead of gameObject to `OnClick()` field? so you should attach it to gameObject so place it there. do you use `public access modifier` in your code?

Comment: is LevelLoader added to a gameObject?

Comment: @smkplus I updated the question...

Comment: @UriPopov as you can see that I dropped the script file 'LevelLoader' below the Runtime in **On Click** event.

Comment: I am a newbie for Unity. Can you elaborate what do you mean by LevelLoader added to a gameobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you seem to be directly dragging the script to the Onclick event. What you need to do is drag the script onto a game object that is in the scene. Then select that object in the event and then select the script component. Monobehaviours dont work if they are not on a game Object.[image]
[image]